# Automated email when connection to source fails in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

sorry if the question is too basic. I am very new to Azure and I want to receive automated email if a connection to for example a SQL server is not established. In that regard, I was wondering if there is anything like get meta data activity for linked services that could output true or false if a connection is is not established? given that there is such activity, I know how to to the rest of job. I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks in advance

I have searched about it and tried to find the option of linkedservice instead of dataset in some activities settings but have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Logic App in Azure with your Azure Data factory to receive an email when there’s an error.

1. I created a Logic app resource with the connectors as mentioned below:-

[image]

[image]

2. I created an ADF pipeline and sent an email on my Outlook when I received an error like below:-

My copy data activity failed like below:-

[image]

Now, I’ll add one control flow on Web Activity that will trigger our Logic app to send an Email alert.

Added my Logic app URL in the Web activity URL and content-type set to application/json :
[image]

[image]

Added the dynamic content in the body to get the Error message and details in the email:-

[image]

[image]

As the Copy activity failed, I got an email alert like below:-

[image]

Reference:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email

Answer (score 0):

How about getting an text message with email ? :)
You can create monitoring on a pipeline and on failure it will send an email and also a text message . Please read more on the same here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-alerts-to-proactively-monitor-your-data-factory-pipelines/.

Now for the pipeline , you can add a Lookup actvity and add a simple query like

```
"Select top 1 from someTable"
```

When the connection to the SQL will fail , the activity will fail and also the pipeline . You should get and email and text for the failures .